# How to use support 'Support library' in 'Androidx' project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I want to use this open-source library -- https://github.com/xabaras/RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator

But it only currently supports  Support library and my project uses AndroidX.... is there any way I can make my 'Androidx' project  support it...maybe configurations, etc

Comment: Default project configurations should have [Jetifier](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/jetifier) enabled which remaps support packages to androidX. Does your project not compile? If so whats the error you receive?

Comment: Thanks alot @Pawel, enabling jetifier solved the issue, I actually enabled it before it didn't work...maybe I did some things wrong..  but now it works perfectly fine. Thanks